# Reverse Name search using Kanavan Autosearch in Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, autocomplete, search-engine

I am using karavan autosearch extention for magento1.7. and I want to modify the searching technique. In that search technique if we provide a full or partial name, the search engine works perfectly. but I want it works for reverse name. I mean If the exact name is 'test product', then if I use 'product test', that result will show same product in dropdown product list, what is now became empty. I have debug it and found that this search engine also using magento default search technique.
Any kind of Idea is acceptable.Please help me..
Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karavan extension uses default Magento  search Model as backbone

app\code\local\Mage\CatalogSearch\Model\Resource\Search\collection.php

Find method _getSearchEntityIdsSql() and change there as u required.

```
$words = array();
    if(str_word_count($this->_searchQuery)>1){
            $words = explode(" ",$this->_searchQuery);
    }
    $ifValueId = $this->getConnection()->getCheckSql('t2.value_id > 0', 't2.value', 't1.value');
    foreach ($tables as $table => $attributeIds) {
        foreach($words as $word){
            $selects[] = $this->getConnection()->select()
                        ->from(array('t1' => $table), 'entity_id')
                        ->joinLeft(
                            array('t2' => $table),
                            $this->getConnection()->quoteInto(
                                't1.entity_id = t2.entity_id AND t1.attribute_id = t2.attribute_id AND t2.store_id = ?',
                                $this->getStoreId()),
                            array()
                        )
                    ->where('t1.attribute_id IN (?)', $attributeIds)
                    ->where('t1.store_id = ?', 0)
                    ->where($resHelper->getCILike($ifValueId, $word, $likeOptions));
        }
        if ($selects) {
            $likeCond = '(' . join(' and ', $selects) . ')';
        }

    }
```

Some what like this.

Note: DOnt overwrite BAse Class